# Get time in HTML tags using curl and grep/sed/awk

Tags: regex, bash, curl, awk, sed

I'm trying to extract just the arrival times from this web page. I'm running this in terminal on OSX 10.9.5

http://www.flyokc.com/Arrivals.aspx

I've come as far as isolating just the tags

```
curl 'www.flyokc.com/arrivals.aspx' | grep 'labelTime'
```

However, I'm terrible at RegEx so I haven't figured out just to grab the times from these tags. Thoughts on how I can do that?

Eventually, I'd like to group them by the hour of the day and display the number of arrivals by hour, in descending order

Comment: You mean this `curl 'www.flyokc.com/arrivals.aspx' | grep -oP 'labelTime">\K[^<>]*'` ?

Comment: It doesn't like that
curl 'www.flyokc.com/arrivals.aspx' | grep -oP 'labelTime">\K[^<>]*'
  0usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
  5  310k    5 17079    0     0  33998      0  0:00:09 --:--:--  0:00:09 33954
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1448)

Comment: try xmllint for parsing html/xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing HTML/XML with regex is bad. That being sad, this seems to work at this moment for your use case:

```
gawk '
BEGIN{
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"
    FS="[<>: ]+"
}
/labelTime/&&/ContentPlaceHolderMain/{
    if($6="PM") a[$4+12]+=1
    else a[$4]+=1
}
END{
    for(h in a)
        print h, a[h]
}' <(curl 'www.flyokc.com/arrivals.aspx' 2>/dev/null)
```

Edit: An account of what works why:

- Set the field separator to the html delimiters, spacing, and HH:MM seperator.
- Then grab the sixth field (Hours) 
  (this is only in a sense a regex what you asked for...)
- If the sixth field is "PM", add 12 hours to it (you want to sort numerically in the end). +1 the count for that hour.
- After processing of input, display the results. Because the array access order has been defined to sort numerically on the keys, no need to external sort commands are necessary.

Comment: Output I got from that is as follows
22 10
23 4
24 3
13 1
14 7
15 3
16 13
17 4
18 7
19 8
20 5
21 6
That's hour of day and count, correct?

Answer (score 2):

If you're simply looking to grab the arrival times such as 12:00 PM, etc. `awk` with `curl` should work:

```
curl -s 'http://flyokc.com/arrivals.aspx' | awk '/labelTime/{print substr($2,68,5),substr($3,1,2)}'
```

Output:

```
12:47 PM
...
```

How it works:

`CURL` silently grabs the source of the webpage, then `AWK` takes the output and uses "labelTime" to pick out the line which contains the arrival times. Since awk grabs the entire `<span>` where the string resides, substring is used to start at position 68, then the result is printed.

Comment: This works correctly, thank you. The other answer groups them by hour and outputs a count, but I had added that request later on. I appreciate your answer.